# The Module "zkemkeeper.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found

Tags: c#, dll, regsvr32, dllregistration

![DLL error][1]

As per the previous observation on Stack overflow i tried the following steps

A- Ran CMD Prompt as administrator and tried to register it.
B- As i need to use this DLL in .net code, i have made the changes in .net Tragetframe work as "x64".
C- Tried using dependency walker as well. However, it shows that the dependent DLL are available and none are missing.
D - Tried unregister and re-register. However, during un-register dll it throws the same error.
E- Tried using Dump dlls as well. The dump doesn't help me to fix the error.
F- Tried fixing the registry by using the software"Free Window Registry Repair tool" in case i have corrupted registries.
G- There was no option for me to go to Accessories-> Systems Tools - > Windows recovery and reboot the system.

### OS - Details

MS Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise sever- 64 Bit

Kindly assist me here and let me know if you need any further information to be added. Feeling bit painful as its like a dead fish in the water.

Comment: Also , for .NET the DLLS were not registered with Regsam no use ( Currently using .NET framework 4.5 & VS2012).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue Solution i simple.

Need follow the below steps
1) Run the command prompt as Admin
2) Remove the DLL from SysWOW64 folder by using Erase Commandd
3) Register the DLL using Regsvr32

The DLL is registered.